# mysql service can't restart

Tags: mysql, service, lamp, restart

I tried to start mysql using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`,
as well as restart using `sudo restart mysql` and `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` but nothing happens. When I try these types of commands, apache and php are fine, but I always have a problem with mysql, i don't understand. It works good for some time and then just turns off.

If I reinstall all of its packages, it works, but I don't want to constantly deal with it.

Using `systemctl status mysql.service` I get:

> ```
> mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor 
> preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-07-12 16:06:18 CEST; 
> 7min ago
> Process: 9231 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid- 
> file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Process: 9222 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
> (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> ```

Can somebody help me? I'm new with this. I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Edit /etc/my.cnf, and add the following line under the         
[mysqld] heading.
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
Then restart: $ service mysql restart
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-on-ubuntu-keeps-crashing

Comment: I get this `/etc/mysql/my.cnf: editing symbolic links is not permitted` . Is same if i do that in mysql.cnf? Should I put that under this #
# The MySQL database server configuration file. :((